# Nexux Indexes not getting updated automatically in sonatype 2.11.1-01 for yum repositry

Tags: jenkins, nexus

we are using nexus sonatype 2.11.1-01 and creating yum repository to save artifacts like rpm pom files
but we notice that after yum repo is modified like rpms are added then indexes are not getting updated
do we have any fix for this in sonatype because we cant afford manula fixes in CI jenkins?

Comment: Have you looked into utilizing scheduled tasks?  Specifically wondering if "Update Repositories Index" helps you.  My understanding is this is normally done automatically so I am wondering if yo're publishing weirdly somehow.  Ref: https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM2/Managing+Scheduled+Tasks